# Selecting all the HTML elements (label) where a CSS class not applied in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to select all the labels from a view where a specific CSS class not applied to it.

### CSS

```
.ondemand-field[readonly]
{
    color: #848284;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

### VIEW

```
<table>
     <tr>
          <td class="display-label">@Html.LabelFor(t => t.ProductId, new { @class = "ondemand-field" })</td>
          <td class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(t => t.ProductId)</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <td class="display-label">@Html.LabelFor(t => t.ISBN)</td>
          <td class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(t => t.ISBN)</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <td class="display-label">@Html.LabelFor(t => t.Title)</td>
          <td class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(t => t.Title)</td>
     </tr>

</table>
```

### JavaScript

```
$('#OnDemandData').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
       //Select all the HTML elements where ondemand-field CSS class not applied

    }
    else {
        //TODO
    }
});
```

The idea is once all the elements are selected , I can add the ondemand-field CSS class with "readonly" attribute so that the label color get changed.

-Alan-

Comment: Why should this question be re-opened? It's an duplicate. The Op could have found that link if he had google'd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.not()` selector to exclude the specific class from the matched set of elements:

```js
var notOnDemand = $('.element').not('.ondemand-field');
notOnDemand.css({ 'color':'red' });
```

```css
.element {
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid #d8d8d8;
  margin:2px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Apply red color to all exept '.ondemand-field'</h1>
<div class='element'>Element</div>
<div class='element ondemand-field'>Element (ondemand-field)</div>
<div class='element'>Element</div>
<div class='element ondemand-field'>Element (ondemand-field)</div>
<div class='element'>Element</div>
```

Comment: Is this going to work if the view is a partial view?

Answer (score 1):

Yuu can use [**`not()`**](http://api.jquery.com/not/) or **[`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot)** pseudoclass.

```
$('yourElements').not('.ondemand-field');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this : You can use `:not` to get non demand-field elements.

```
$('#OnDemandData').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
       //Select all the HTML elements where ondemand-field CSS class not applied
       var nonOnDemand = $(document).find(':not(.ondemand-field)');
    }
    else {
        //TODO
    }
});
```